# How to generate a treeview in html from flexible xml just in client side

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

Could anyone please give me an example in this? I have found many but they didn't match my requirement.

The treeview must have expand and collapse, the xml is flexible, which means I should test if a node is exist, and there are many may appear many times and with different contents. Also, I need it works just in client side, nothing to do with the sever or net.  And I wonder if it's possible to display the treeview in the left frame, and the content on the right frame.

In fact, I need these files, maybe have xslt, js, css etc. to be send to the users, then they can click on the xml or html to see the treeview of their owen xmls (all of them have the same DTD)

Thank u very much

Allen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You asked for examples... I can provide links to online samples:

1. [TreeMenu](http://treemenu.net)
2. [dTree](http://destroydrop.com/javascripts/tree)
3. [BlueShoes JS Tree](http://blueshoes.org/en/javascript/tree)
4. [Morten's JS Tree](http://treemenu.org)
5. [CodeThat Tree](http://codethat.com/javascript-tree.html) - XML support.

If you have loaded the tree into a page, you can use a left frame to load that particular page.